# $H<Aut(p)$ for a covering $p:E\longrightarrow B$, $B$ locally path-connected $\implies \bar p: E/H \longrightarrow B$ is a covering

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Assume a subgroup $H<\mathrm{Aut}(p)$, where $\mathrm{Aut}(p)$ is the automorphism group of a covering $p:E \longrightarrow B\,$, i.e. $\alpha$ is a homeomorphism over $E$ and $p\alpha = p$. If $B$ is locally path-connected, then we have an induced map
$$
q=\bar p:\, E/H \longrightarrow B
$$

Show that it is a covering.

**Note**: I will provide an answer right away. The proof fills the gaps of Dieck's argument in his book "Algebraic Topology".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Observe that if $p$ is trivial over some open set $U \subset B$, then it is also trivial over any of its (nonempty) open subsets.
2. Also, one can prove that the path components of a locally path connected space are open (see proposition **3.1.5** in Dieck's AT).

Let $\chi \in B$ and $p$ be trivial over an open set $U \subset B$ containing $\chi$.
By assumption, we find a path-connected neighborhood $\chi \in V \subset U$; this in turn contains a neighborhood $\chi \in O \subset V \subset U$ that is open in $B$.
Now, $O$ is locally path-connected, because $B$ is and $O$ is open in $B$.
It is partitioned by its path-components, which are open in $O$ by point 2. and hence also open in $B$, since $O$ is open in $B$. Hence, we find an open, path-connected neighborhood $W$ of $\chi$. W.l.o.g., using the preceding argument and poin 1. assume $U=W$.

We have seen that $U$ can be chosen as open and path-connected and be evenly covered by $p$. Since $p$ induces a homeomorphism from each sheet onto $U$, we see that the $U_i$ are the partition of $p^{-1}(U)$ into its path components. A little argument shows that each $h \in \mathrm{Aut}(p)$ permutes the sheets (i.e., the $U_i$). Define an equivalence relation on the set $\mathfrak{I}$ indexing the sheets
$$
i\sim j\; :\hspace{-1.5mm}\iff \exists h \in \mathrm{Aut}(p)\bigl(\,h(U_i)=U_j\,\bigr)
$$
Then, if $\mathop{can}: E \longrightarrow E/H$ denotes the canonical projection into the orbit under the left-action of $H$,

$$
\mathop{can}(U_i) \cap \mathop{can}(U_j) = \emptyset \text{ for } i \not\sim j
$$
because if $x \in \mathop{can}(U_i) \cap \mathop{can}(U_j)$, then we have
$h.u = v$ for some $h \in H,\,u\in U_i,\, v \in U_j$, implying $h(U_i) = U_j$, because $h$ permutes the sheets and can only map into one path-component (we haven't shown that $h$ maps each sheet *onto* some other sheet, but this isn't hard to show).
Also,
$$
can(U_i) = can(U_j) \text{ for } i \sim j
$$
because
$$
can(U_i) = \bigcup_{u\in U_i} \Bigl{\{}{ \bigcup_{h \in H} \{h(u)\}} \Bigr{\}}
$$
and, for suitable $\alpha \in H$,
$$
can(U_j) = can(\alpha(U_i)) = \bigcup_{u\in U_i} \Bigl{\{}{ \bigcup_{h \in H} \{h\alpha(u)\}} \Bigr{\}} =
\bigcup_{u\in U_i} \Bigl{\{}{ \bigcup_{h \in (H)\alpha} \{h(u)\}} \Bigr{\}} =
\bigcup_{u\in U_i} \Bigl{\{}{ \bigcup_{h \in H} \{h(u)\}} \Bigr{\}}
$$
where $(H)\alpha = H$ denotes the image under right-translation of the group $H$ by group isomorphism $\alpha$. It is not hard to show that the $can(U_i)$ are in fact open, so we have that
$$
\bigcup_{\bar{i} \in I/\sim} can(U_i)
$$
is in fact a disjoint union of open sets, each of which is homeomorphic to $U$ through $q=\bar{p}$ (see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341003/injectivity-of-map-induced-by-covering-pe-longrightarrow-b).

This shows that $q$ is trivial over $U$ (with discrete fibers).

Conclude that $q$ is a covering.